# How to run last viewed activity after resume?

Tags: java, android

I've got an android application. If I go through activities(for example MainTabActivity->SearchMapActivity->ListBranchesActivity) and then hide(not close) my application, android will run the main (MainTabActivity) activity after reopen. If I press "back" button, android will show me the last activity (ListBranchesActivity). How can I make my app show the last activity after resuming? I really have no idea how to achieve that. Somebody says to add `singleTask` statement to manifest.
My manifest:

```
 <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" 
       android:largeHeap="true"  >  


        <activity
            android:name=".SearchMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"> 

            <intent-filter>             
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>         

            <activity
            android:name=".UpdateActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"> 
                    <intent-filter>             
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity> 

            <activity
            android:name=".CompanyInfoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"> 
                    <intent-filter>             
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity> 

            <activity
            android:name=".FullMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"> 
                <intent-filter>             
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>        
            </activity> 

            <activity
            android:name=".ListBranchesActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"> 
                <intent-filter>             
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>        
            </activity> 

            <activity
            android:name=".ListCompaniesByBranchActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"> 
                <intent-filter>             
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>        
            </activity> 

            <activity
            android:name=".SearchResultActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">  


                <intent-filter>             
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>        
            </activity> 



        <activity
            android:name=".MainTabActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />                
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Also that thing doesn't happen everytime. Sometimes it shows last activity, sometimes - main activity.

Comment: what do you mean by *then hide(not close) my application*?

Comment: I mean "go to main menu of my android device"

Comment: What you want is the default behaviour. So, you must have tinkered with activity flags, launch modes for your app to behave this way. Post your manifest and the intent flags code to launch B and C.

Comment: What is "intent flags"?

Comment: I meant any special activity flags set on the intent used to then start B or C. Could you also identify which one's A, B, C in all those activities in your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

```
 > Also that thing doesn't happen everytime. Sometimes 
 > it shows last activity, sometimes - main activity.
```

Sometime android closes your app if it needs memory. So even if you `hide(not close) ...[the] application,` it might have been closed anyway